# How to display the current "Day of the Week" next to the 24H time in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, taskbar, calendar, date-time

I would like to see a short two letter **day of the week** abbreviation like `MO` for Monday `SA` for Saturday before the 24H time dusplay on windows 10.

As you can there's plenty of room there. For most beautiful effect the 24H display should be aligned to the right and the preceding day of the week abbreviation `MO` aligned to left.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

---

Update Thank you gentlemen my partial Success see screen shot below and +1 on all your true answers and comments! Now to the next and Final phase:

A. How to place the date abbreviation in front of the time, marked with X !?
B. How to Capitalize the first letter so it becomes more apparent and neat?
C. Happy new year!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Short two letter day of the week like `MO` or `SA`  and next to time may not be possible without 3rd party tools. But with the approach mentioned below, you can get 3 letter day like `Mon` or `Sat` beside date.

Go to `Control Panel` >> `Region`. 

Then select `Additional Settings` from the Region window.

Select the `Date` tab. Under Short date, add `ddd` at the start to make it appear as:

  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍`ddd-dd-MM-yy` or `ddd, dd-MM-yy`

If you use hyphen, you'll see it separated from the date by hyphen and if you use comma, you'll see it separated from the date by comma. Note that this will display only 3 alphabets of the day. If you want to see all the alphabets of the day, use the following instead:

  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍`dddd-dd-MM-yy` or  `ddd, dd-MM-yy`

Comment: This only works if you have "use small icons in taskbar" set to disabled, otherwise you won't even see the date, and that is required. Also, seeing 2 or 3 letters (and the language) is determined by the language settings. English uses 3 letters, Dutch uses 2.

Comment: @LPChip You're right but the image that the OP showed in the question indicates that  "use small icons in taskbar"  is already set to disabled. I didn't know that the number of letters, that appear, depend on the language settings. I won't mind if you edit and improve my answer. 

Comment: Yes, of course. But this is a Q&A style site, where other users with similar problems find the same post. One may want the same thing and think your answer is not working only because they use small icons.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other answer, showing the day of the week next to time on taskbar is only possible with a third party tool. If you are open to this, [T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock) can achieve what you want, as well as all sorts of other customizations on Windows taskbar clock.

As for your second question, capitalization of the first letter seems to be locale-dependent. It is capitalized in English, but not in Dutch, your locale. This is determined by Windows, and the program has no option to change it. If you don't mind seeing the day abbreviation in English, you can change your locale to English in T-Clock (affects only the taskbar, not the rest of Windows), or use the option `dde` instead of `ddd` for English day abbreviations.