# Windows 10 Normal and Small Taskbar mode whilst keeping "Day of the Week & Date" shown at all times

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar, date-time

In Windows 10, in "large icons" taskbar mode (32x32 taskbar program icons), I see the date plus first two letters of the week (Dutch) showing nicely:

[image]

But, when I activate "use small taskbar buttons" mode (16x16 taskbar program icons) then the whole date and first two letters of the wek disappear!

I understand that there isn't room above or below, but there is plenty of room aside it! So I would like to see the date left or right of the time displayed at all times!

How to achieve this? I am open for registry hacks if that is what it takes to show the date in my taskbar at all times.

[image]

The reverese opposite of what I want and perhaps related is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1202069/how-to-disable-day-of-the-week-in-extended-taskbar-on-windows-10).
Also related is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1162012/how-to-display-the-current-day-of-the-week-next-to-the-24h-time-in-windows-10) how to show the first two letter abbreviation of the day of the week ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a native Windows solution to achieve this. Here is a [feedback about that feature request](https://aka.ms/Jezeg4) if you want to upvote it. (It was linked from [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_taskbar/how-do-i-always-see-the-date-with-small-taskbar/0b0f6161-582b-4b01-acb0-849a0b5bcd75) discussing this issue.)

However, I found a nice third party solution: [T-Clock](https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock) allows you to configure Windows taskbar clock. I came across it in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/acglk0/the_taskbar_looks_much_cleaner_with_a_date_and/), where you can see an example of single line date and time (that image has regular size taskbar, but it works just the same in small taskbar mode). It is very customizable; e.g. you can keep it with two lines even in small taskbar mode if you don't mind it looking a bit cramped, or single line as in the image, adding and removing the elements you want (day of the week, year, etc.).